# Usefulness of Laplacians for directed graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, machine-learning, graph-laplacian

Are laplacians for directed graphs used in any algorithms ? For example laplacians for the undirected graphs are used in algorithms such as spectral clustering.

Comment: http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/NIPS2006_638.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about spectral clustering, but here is one use of Laplacians in directed graphs I do know.

[Kirchhoff's matrix tree theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_theorem) gives that the number of spanning trees on a directed (multi)graph in the determinant of the reduced Laplacian. With the appropriate definitions the the theorem also holds for directed graphs, see [here](http://people.reed.edu/~davidp/412/handouts/matrix-tree.pdf). As the link shows you can weight your edges how ever you like and count "weighted directed spanning trees" with a specified root.